# How dangerous is it to use textmods from internet sources?

Tags: third-party

I have been playing a game (`.exe` file  downloaded from Internet) that supports the use of Textmods (altering of the game code in terms of textures) so long as they only affect visuals, and not actual game mechanics (leveling, trading, etc.).

I am a bit skeptical to download these Textmods since they come from a third party source on the Internet. How can I verify that it is indeed safe to use the text mods, and what dangers can stem from downloading these Textmods?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term "textmod" (and I assume others are too). Can you either give some description of what exactly you're downloading, or give a link to the thing you're talking about? Ideally both. It would also be super helpful to know what kind of game - in-browser flash game? Downloaded `.exe` game? etc

Comment: see changes made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing about the precise game/mods involved, it's only really possible to discuss the risks in abstract.

From what you've said the application processes a file (textmod) which is downloaded from a 3rd party. So to process any data an application is going to need to open the file, read it, parse it, and then act on the instructions therein.

If there is a bug in the parsing code, for example, depending on the language the original program is coded in, you may get something like a buffer overflow or other undesired condition.

Assuming that this occurs, you then would look at impact which in the case of a game being run by the user, is likely to allow the malicious program to execute code with the privileges of the application (likely user-level).

In terms of mitigation, well at a basic level you could open the text mod files and see if they appear to be well formed and lacking obvious attack signatures (e.g. writing much larger quantities of data than might be otherwise expected in a field)

At a more advanced level it would be possible to write code to parse and validate the correctness of the file (assuming that there's a specification available) which could use to check textmods before loading them.

Comment: Your answer is completely correct, however I would like to add that I have *never* heard of this being used as an attack vector. Yes it can be done. I do even know of buffer overflows being used constructively by modders to enhance the game (starcraft). I would not be too scared. The usual sophistication of „infected game mods“ is that the mod contains a readme.exe...

Answer (score 1):

Ah - texture mods, gotcha. The high-level answer is that while textures don't tend to contain executable code, shaders certainly do. So depending on what these mods are doing, you could well be downloading and running arbitrary code. Do so at your own risk. At the very least, I would only download textmods from reputable sources, that have good reviews and stuff.

Personally, I keep a Windows install just for gaming and I assume that it's infected as hell. Since I like to install game mods and keystroke / macro tools, I don't trust that OS with anything beyond my email password - for everything else I use my linux laptop.

Comment: Shaders also tend to run sandboxed (vertices in, pixel colours out, no access to external resources), BUT graphics driver bugs are common.